# How do I delete directory trees via batch file on Windows 7?

Tags: windows-7, batch-file

I want to delete the whole content of a specified folder on Windows 7 via batch file. My problem is, that 'del' or 'erase' only deletes the files, not the folders and 'rmdir' or 'rd' always deletes the specified folder with its content, but I only want to delete the content, not the folder itself. I tried the command '`rmdir /S /Q "C:\Share\*"`' which gave me a syntax error.

What is the correct way to do this?

I am working on Windows 7 Professional 64-bit and have admin permissions.

Answer (score 41, accepted):

Your batch file will need to run two commands, one to clear out the files then one to remove the child directories. I've assumed the directory you want to remove is `C:\Share\`

The batch file should look something like this:

```
del /s /f /q c:\share\*.*
for /f %%f in ('dir /ad /b c:\share\') do rd /s /q c:\share\%%f
```

`del /s /f /q` will recursively search through the directory tree deleting any files (even read only files) without prompting for confirmation.

The second line loops through all the sub directories (which should now be empty) and removes them.

Short of deleting the entire folder and recreating it (which I don't think you want to do due to permissions?) this should be the easiest way to clean the folder out.

Comment: If I do a little correction here 
"for /f %%f" -> "for /f %f" then it works fine :) Thank you very much.

Comment: `del` is not necessary. `rd/s/q` will delete both files and subfolders.

Comment: @grawity the `del` is mainly there for any files in the root folder, could remove the recursion switch though.

Comment: @MichaelK, %%f is for use in batch files, %f for when it's a single command straight to the command line.

Comment: If any of the subdirectory names contain spaces, you can add "delims=" to process them correctly (for /f **"delims="** %%f in ...):  See http://stackoverflow.com/q/5553040/64918

Comment: To delete everything from your folder and hide stderr messages: `del /f/q "c:\path to\your folder\*" 2>nul:&&for /f "delims=" %G in ('"dir /ad/b "c:\path to\your folder\" 2>nul:"')do @rd /s/q "c:\path to\your folder\%G"`

Answer (score 30):

```
rmdir /s/q C:\Share
```

You get a "Syntax error" because `rmdir` only accepts complete names, not wildcards. (In `cmd.exe`, wildcard expansion is left to the individual programs; not all of them do.)

If you have many directories starting with `Share...`, use a *`for`* loop.

```
for /d %f in (C:\Share*) do rmdir /s/q "%f"
```

Comment: I do not want to delete the share folder.

Answer (score 13):

Try this in a command prompt:

```
rd /s/q "C:\Share"
```

Comment: This removed parent folder as well, not content of the folder.

Answer (score 5):

What about ?

```
rmdir /S /Q "target"
mkdir "target
```

EDIT: of course this solution applicable only when you can tolerate a momentary folder absence.

Comment: This would delete the original folder.

Comment: @MichaelK My task was able to tolerate a momentary folder absence, so I went with this solution. I thought, that it is simpler and more readable than `for /f` in cases similar to mine. Just wanted to share

Answer (score 2):

```
for /f "delims=" %%f in ('dir /ad /b c:\share\') do rd /s /q c:\share\%%f
```

This does not work if the subdirectories contain other directories that contain spaces.

In order to make this work, I needed to quote the final string, like this

```
for /f "delims=" %%f in ('dir /ad /b c:\share\') do rd /s /q "c:\share\%%f"
```

Apparently, this causes the command to work on the quoted string instead of just the string itself.

Answer (score 1):

simply:

rmdir /s /q "path"

mkdir "path"

Comment: This is a duplicate of [this answer](https://superuser.com/a/952303/213131).

Answer (score 0):

I would try this in the folder where all subfolders should be deleted but the root (and files in the root) left as they are:
for /D %v in (*) do rd /s/q %v

for /D matches directories
and rd/s/q deletes each at a time