# How do I delete directory trees on remote via bat file?

Tags: batch-file

I saw  the question "[How do I delete directory trees via console on Windows 7?](https://superuser.com/questions/328281/how-do-i-delete-directory-trees-via-console-on-windows-7/328306#328306)" Would like to do the same thing with the following exceptions:

- The directory exists on an external drive .
- The path to the directory has a space in the string.
- I definitely want this in a batch file, and not on the command line.

So for me I am dealing with:

```
del /s /f /q p:\group_share\my share\*.*
for /f %%f in ('dir /ad /b p:\group_share\my share\') do rd /s /q p:\group_share\my share\%f
```

Obviously I could put it in a variable:

```
set FULL_PATH="p:\group_share\my share\"
```

Then:

```
del /s /f /q %FULL_PATH%*.*
for /f %%f in ('dir /ad /b %FULL_PATH%') do rd /s /q %FULL_PATH%%f
```

I have tried adding quotes around the  %FULL_PATH% ergo: "%FULL_PATH" ... but I get this:

```
The system cannot find the file specified.
```

By the way, the first line works if I put in: p:\group_share\my share\ with quotes around it:

```
 del /s /f /q "p:\group_share\my share\"*.*
```

Can anyone give me a suggestion or something to try? I have tried all sorts of permutations of quotation marks, no quotation marks etc. Thanks Geo

Answer (score 1):

You seem to be making it unnecessarily complicated - all you need is:-

```
pushd %FULL_PATH%
rd /s /q .
popd
```

By moving to the target directory you protect `my share` from deletion. Note that `cd` and `pushd` do not need quotes, as they take only one argument.